# How do I fix "InPageError" crash in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I suddenly started getting an "InPageError" crash in VS last week. The error happens when attempting to open a solution or when trying to create a new project. It also happens when using msbuild from the command line.

I've tried everything that comes to mind to fix this, including numerous hours of research on the web. I applied quite a few updates from Windows Update last week, including updates for VS and for MS Office. I went through and removed all these, I uninstalled iTunes which I had just upgraded, and I uninstalled another application which I installed around the same time. I tried running VS in safe mode, and I tried resetting all VS settings to default. I ran chkdsk /f on my drive and it did find a few bad sectors and fixed them.

None of this seemed to help, so I decided to leave everything alone for a while (Friday to Sunday) and what do you know, suddenly VS came up without the crash yesterday, and worked flawless. After things started working yesterday I did reapply my VS settings, I reapplied Windows Updates, and I reinstalled the application I previously uninstalled. VS continued to work.

This morning, though, I'm getting the crash again, and I'm back to square one, not having any idea what the source of the problem is. So, anyone with a solution or insights?

**Details:**

"Microsoft Visual Studio has encountered a problem and needs to close."

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   InPageError
  Error Status Code:    c00000b5
  Faulting Media Type:  00000003
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033

I find two entries in the Windows Application Event Log:

Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.40219.1, time stamp: 0x4d5f2a73
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.1008, time stamp: 0x517a1be7
Exception code: 0xc0000006
Fault offset: 0x00006680
Faulting process id: 0x130c
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceef89e76ac906
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 389154b1-5b7d-11e3-a7f8-f0def11d2248

---

Windows cannot access the file C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.Build\de24e9111354bdacab0e578fe8146d9a\Microsoft.Build.ni.dll for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 because of this error.

Program: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
File: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.Build\de24e9111354bdacab0e578fe8146d9a\Microsoft.Build.ni.dll

The error value is listed in the Additional Data section.
User Action
1. Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again.
2. If the file still cannot be accessed and
    - It is on the network, your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem with the network and that the server can be contacted.
    - It is on a removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the disk is fully inserted into the computer.
3. Check and repair the file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run, type CMD, and then click OK. At the command prompt, type CHKDSK /F, and then press ENTER.
4. If the problem persists, restore the file from a backup copy.
5. Determine whether other files on the same disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard disk, contact your administrator or computer hardware vendor for further assistance.

Additional Data
Error value: C00000B5
Disk type: 3

---

I found some details about the errors:

0xC00000B5 STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT
{Device Timeout} The specified I/O operation on %hs was not completed before the time-out period expired.

0xC0000006 STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR
The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The required data was not placed into memory because of an I/O error status of 0x%08lx.

Comment: This means your hard drive has a bad sector. I strongly recommend replacing it before it dies completely.

Comment: You get this problem when the executable or DLL on a location which can suddenly not be accessed anymore while the application is running.  A typical case is: exe is on network and network connection is dropped.  But also corrupt CD (probably not in your case) or bad hard disk sector can cause this.

Comment: @Patrick In this case the file is in C:\Windows\assembly\... so it's on the hard drive.

Comment: Although I had checked my drive earlier, I checked it again through the Windows UI and asked it to "attempt recovery of bad sectors". It turned out I had a few more of those, which were recovered. Btw, the disk is an SSD. I'm not convinced the disk is dying, I'm suspicious the bad sectors have been around for a while. Anyway, I'm doing backups. Thanks Raymond for convincing me to check the disk again.